# Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException: Unable to access an account or mailbox

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

> **Sidenote 1**: I've seen this topic come by a few times before, but most > are unresolved and the rest is not really related to my problem.

---

> **Sidenote 2**: Don't get confused by the usage of the parameters, I did some adjustments in the code so it would fit in SO. The parameters are not the issue here.

---

I'm trying to develop a way for me to read emails out of a functional mailbox. At this point I want to get access to the mailboxes in general, so I'm seeing if I can read the mails in my own mailbox.
However something seems to be wrong. As soon as it tries to run the **`service.FindItems(inbox, fView)`** method, it'll give me the following error message:

`Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException: Unable to access an account or mailbox.`

At this point I'm not sure whether it has to do with credentials, or with access rights. Below is the code I'm using.

I'm triggering a helper method I created:

```
FindItemsResults<Item> items = ExchangeWebServiceHelper.GetEmailsFromFolder(inboxName);
```

In the ExchangeWebServiceHelper I have the following two methods:

```
public static ExchangeService CreateConnection()
{
    string url = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EWSAsmxUrlNp"];

    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(
        Object obj,
        X509Certificate certificate,
        X509Chain chain,
        SslPolicyErrors errors)
    {
        return true;
    };

    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
    service.Url = new Uri(url);

    service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

    return service;
}

public static FindItemsResults<Item> GetEmailsFromFolder(Mailbox mailbox)
{
    ExchangeService service = CreateConnection();

    FolderView fView = new FolderView(100);
    fView.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, FolderSchema.DisplayName);
    FolderId inbox = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);

    FindItemsResults<Item> results = service.FindItems(inbox, fView);

    Logger.Log(mailbox.ToString());
    Logger.Log(results.TotalCount.ToString());

    return results;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried by setting: `service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(your_user, your_pass);`?

Comment: I was thinking about that, but what do I set the username and password to when you're building the application where multiple people use this? I'm gonna try to look for it, but I've read that I could techncially use `UseDefaultCredentials` when you work with Exchange.

Comment: Is this Windows Forms app or ASP.Net app? If it's Asp.Net app you need to configure impersonation with windows authentication.

Comment: So basically you mean I should add Windows Authentication to the asp.net application and then get the username and password out like that?

Comment: So it's asp.net app? It's a bit tricky to get this scenario to work and it depents on your requirements. I'm guessing the app residing on server A has Windows authentication enabled, then you need to turn on [impersonation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh507fc5.aspx) but this is still not enough. The Exchange is located most likely on server B and the authenticated credentials on server A cannot be passed to server B unless you turn on [Active directory delegation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169022(v=ws.10).aspx). Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, I'll need the luck lol. Where do I turn on the AD delegation? On the Exchange server or on the App server?

Comment: The server A needs to be trusted/allowed to delegate in Active Directory, one article about it [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/autz_auth_stuff/2011/05/03/kerberos-delegation/). Basic authentication is also one option (doesn't need impersonation or delegation), but then the users always have to login to the app.

Comment: Nah we don't want them to log in, so I guess it'll have to be the hard way. I'll take look at it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft Dev Center](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservicebase.usedefaultcredentials(v=exchg.80).aspx), you cannot use `.UseDefaultCredentials = true` for Exchange OnLine.

> **Remarks**
>
> Setting the UseDefaultCredentials property to true automatically sets
>   the Credentials property to a null reference (Nothing in Visual
>   Basic).
>
> **You cannot use the default credentials of the logged on user if the user’s mailbox is hosted in Exchange Online or Exchange Online as part
>   of Office 365**. Instead, use the Credentials property to set the
>   user’s credentials. The user’s credentials must be in user principal
>   name (UPN) form for Exchange Online.

Comment: I'm not really good with Exchange etc.. We're using outlook with a Microsoft Exchange account. I don't think we use the Office 365 version, only the Outlook tool.

Comment: Where is located your Exchange Server? Locally in your datacenter?

Comment: Not on the same server as where my app will be hosted. Let's say my app will be on server A and Exchange is on server B

Comment: But this server is located in your company and can be found in your Active Directory?

Comment: I guess so, I'll check that later today to be sure.